# Which font family is chosen in Windows 10 when I type a non-existent one in Delphi app?

Tags: windows, delphi, fonts

I type in Delphi app:

`Font.Name:= 'Monotype';`

But such font `Monotype` does not exist in Windows (not listed in fonts) and Windows chooses some font. How can I know which font family name is then used?
I ask because Windows chose a really good font but I prefer to specify the correct font family name in my app than some random font in a user's computers.

Segoe UI left, Monotype center, Microsoft Sans Serif right(bold):

[image: Segoe UI left, Monotype center, Microsoft Sans Serif right][image]

Comment: Are you sure you don't simply get the default system font (Segoe UI)?

Comment: Yes, it looks differently i add foto above

Comment: Usually, Microsoft Sans Serif will be substituted.

Comment: @Brian To which WIndows versions and which font versions does your comment apply?

Comment: @Brian no, it is not Microsoft Sans Serif, i have added it to the message above. Is there some api to read what is choosen?

Comment: There are various find font in a bitmap tools. Work better with a higher resolution bitmap and a larger variety of characters. Commonly used to find what font was used in bitmaps used on webpages.